# When running a ruby script via nohup, why doesn't puts write to nohup.out

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, nohup

I'm trying to run a ruby script with `nohup`:

> nohup ruby script.rb &

This takes hours to run, but logs its progress via `puts`.

Usually, I can look at nohup.out to view the recent output of anything I run with nohup.  However, my ruby script doesn't seem to output anything until it finishes, or is killed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with running commands through `nohup`, but approaching this from a "I'm outputting content to a file and it's only being written after the script exits" type of problem, those are caused by the output being buffered.

So it's very likely that being run through `nohup` (and thus redirecting the `puts` output to **nohup.out**) you lost synchronization. You might need to [`flush`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-flush) occasionally or enable [`sync`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-sync). Since [`puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) is "equivalent to `$stdout.puts`":

```
$stdout.flush # run this, occasionally
# or just
$stdout.sync = true
```